# How is built desktop "webapps" like VSCode

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, visual-studio-code

How "webapps" like Visual Studio or the old Ionic Lab that are applications that runs above a "Chrome" version that provides native powers and also together the web side for the application UI (for example).

Is it just a "Chrome fork" or there is a Framework behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just a "Chrome fork" or there is a Framework behind?

It is a super-set of chromium

Visual studio code is built on [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)